# Approximating sum of Poisson distribution as an integral

Tags: integration, approximation, poisson-distribution

given $P(n)=e^{-\mu}\frac{\mu^n}{n!}$, under what conditions can I meaningfully write

$$\sum_{n=0}^N P(n)\approx\int_0^N dx P(x)  $$

using $x!=\Gamma(x+1)$? It is done nonchalantly in a document I'm reading but I'm not sure what allows us to do it, since the sum is not a Riemann sum and I see no term that might act as the $dx$ in the limit that disappears from the integrand.

Comment: $|\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} P(n) - \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \int _n^{n+1} P(x)dx| \le \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \int_n^{n+1} |P(n)-P(x)|dx \le N\sup_{y \in [0,N]} |P'(y)|dy$.

Comment: @mathworker21 thank you, if you post this as an answer I will accept it